# Storing Key-Value and Value-Key dictionaries in a single table

Tags: dictionary, lua, key-value, lua-table

Would this be okay for example :

```
table = { "Mark", "John", "Paul", "Matt", "Chris", ...}
```

and then

```
for k,v in pairs(table) do table[v] = k end
```

Or should I create two separate tables, one for each pair? Which one is better style?

Comment: Assigning new keys to a table while iterating over it with `pairs` is dangerous, as it causes undefined behavior. See: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a list-like table where the keys are integers and the values are something else like yours, using a single table is a good idea, especially with a bit of meta-magic on it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16787892/204011)).

That being said, in that case, you should use `ipairs` to iterate it, not `pairs`.

For map-like table like this, however, using two tables is better:

```
my_table = {
  foo = "bar",
  spam = "eggs",
  chunky = "bacon",
}
```

(because imagine what would happen if you had this...)

```
my_table = {
  foo = "bar",
  bar = "baz",
}
```

Comment: In general, using a variable named `table` is **not a good idea**.

Comment: @hjpotter92 You're right! I used it because the OP used it, I will edit my answer.